# How to copy groups of cells with NotebookWrite?

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, cells

**Bug fixed**

<sub>CellGrouping -> Manual isn't needed anymore for copying cell groups. They are copied correctly by default.</sub>

---

I'm trying to use:

```
NotebookWrite[nb, NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]];
```

to copy cells from the `EvaluationNotebook[]` to a new notebook `nb`. For this, I move around in the `EvaluationNotebook[]` using different applications of `SelectionMove[nb, ...]`.

Now, I would like to copy the exact same cell groupings of the current document as well, and this doesn't seem to happen. In the newly created notebook `nb`, I just see consecutive cells, without any grouping. Why is that? How can copying of groups be achieved?

Comment: I'm really curious. The information about `CellGroupingRules` is preserved. But even with `CreateDocument[NotebookRead /@ Cells[#], AbsoluteOptions[#]] &@ EvaluationNotebook[]` they are not grouped properly. What is what makes them grouped then?

Comment: @Kuba: thanks for your comment. Anyone have any answer on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba I was about to edit this, but I see you have already edited. Maybe you can edit Nobetook->Notebook? It is an interesting question. In a .nb file you can see that there is some information about grouping. You can also set cell grouping manually. I've played around with all this a little bit when looking at Gabriels previous question (I think). If you don't see another way maybe we have to look at editing the notebook file.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom done. It would be perfect to avoid modifying notebook file. I thought it should be available via standard notebook related functions. We will see, unfortunatelly now I can't focus on this more.

Comment: @Kuba I just have checked your code `CreateDocument[NotebookRead /@ Cells[#], AbsoluteOptions[#]] &@ EvaluationNotebook[]` with version 10.4.1 and found that all cell groups (including manually created) are preserved with the default `CellGrouping -> Automatic`. Looks like it was a bug which is currently fixed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for feedback. I would like to read a good tutorial about cell grouping management. I'm always confused ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, you have to set the option `CellGrouping -> Manual` either for the target notebook, or globally in the **Option Inspector** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). Then the following code works as expected:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{}, CellGrouping -> Manual];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Notebook];
NotebookWrite[nb, NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]];
```

[image]

Comment: I missed this because when I grouped cells with Ctrl+Shift+G then still `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]]` -> `{CellGrouping -> Automatic}`

Comment: @Kuba Grouping only applies to the `EvaluationNotebook[]`. When one copies cells from it the target notebook won't inherit the `Cellgrouping` option value, thus it will be the default `Automatic`.

Comment: You mean `Automatic`!=`Automatic`? because this explains why the following has failed: `CreateDocument[NotebookRead /@ Cells[#], AbsoluteOptions[#]] &@ EvaluationNotebook[]`

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that is indeed strange. I don't know ATM what exactly stores the grouping preferences in the source notebook if not the `$FrontEnd`, `$FrontEndSession` or `EvaluationNotebook[]` (all return `Automatic`). The only thing different in the target is if you hit Ctrl+Shift+E on the non-grouped cells, you'll see something like ``CellGroupingRules->{$CellContext`GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}`` of which the `$CellContext` is missing in the source cell.

Comment: Yes I've seen this part too but I thought is shouldn't matter. This might be a key byt I don't know how to use it :)

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for the comment. I will check it out!

Comment: @IstvánZachar Indeed `$CellContext` was the source of the trouble: currently manually grouped cells get `CellGroupingRules->{"GroupTogetherGrouping", 10000.}` what works as expected, but changing it to ``CellGroupingRules->{$CellContext`GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}`` breaks manual grouping. Added the `bugs` tag to the OP (`CellGrouping -> Manual` currently isn't needed).