# How to group cell type A under cell type B?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, cells

My notebook's groupings for "Subsection" and "SubitemNumbered" are broken:

[image]

And by broken, I mean I wanted it to automatically group like this which I did manually (with lots of control+shift+g)

[image]

Here's my stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]

Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 10}
]

Cell[StyleData["Item"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"InputGrouping", 10},
 CounterIncrements->"Item",
 CounterAssignments->{{"Section", 0}, {"Subsection", 0}},
 FontSize->14,
]

Cell[StyleData["Section"],  CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 1}]

Cell[StyleData["Subsubsection"], "Subsubsection",
  CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 1}]

Cell[StyleData["SubitemNumbered"], "Subsubsection",
  CellGroupingRules->{"SubsectionGrouping", 1}]
```

I've read all the posts on Cell Grouping but I still can't find a straight answer to this question. Here are the posts I've consulted so far:

- [How to implement specific cell grouping behavior?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92005/how-to-implement-specific-cell-grouping-behavior)
- [Making cells group](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/making-cells-group/6019#6019)
- [Is it possible to Print into a collapsable CellGroup?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47231/is-it-possible-to-print-into-a-collapsable-cellgroup)
- [Do ShowGroupOpener and TitleGrouping suffice to control cell grouping?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77696/do-showgroupopener-and-titlegrouping-suffice-to-control-cell-grouping)
- [How to sort cells in a notebook based on cell tags?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/how-to-sort-cells-in-a-notebook-based-on-cell-tags)
- [How to copy groups of cells with NotebookWrite?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32080/how-to-copy-groups-of-cells-with-notebookwrite)
- [SubTitle and SubSubTitle do not group by default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/subtitle-and-subsubtitle-do-not-group-by-default/3006#3006)

... and I'm still utterly confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I fixed it:

```
Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"],
 CellMargins->{{21, 3}, {4, 4}}]

Cell[StyleData[All],
 ShowGroupOpener->False,
 FontFamily->"Avenir"]

Cell[StyleData["Title"],
 CellMargins->{{10, 3}, {4, 4}},
 FontColor-> RGBColor[0,0.0,0.6],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 9}]

Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 CellFrame->{{.5, 0}, {0, .5}},
 CellFrameMargins->8,
 CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0, 0.4, 0.9, 1],
 CellMargins->{{17, 3}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 10},
 WholeCellGroupOpener->True,
 FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0.4, 0.9, 1]]

Cell[StyleData["Subsection"],
 CellFrame->{{.1, .1}, {.1, .1}},
 Background->GrayLevel[0.95],
 CellFrameMargins->10,
 CellFrameColor->GrayLevel[0.8],
 CellMargins->{{30, Inherited}, {5, 2}},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 20},
 WholeCellGroupOpener->True,
 FontColor-> RGBColor[0,0.5,0.8]
]

Cell[StyleData["Subsubsection"],
CellFrame->{{.1, .1}, {.1, 01}},
 Background->RGBColor[0, 0, 0.6, 0.05],
 CellFrameMargins->8,
 CellFrameColor->GrayLevel[0.8],
 CellMargins->{{48, 3}, {0, 0}},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 30},
 FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 0.6, 1],
 WholeCellGroupOpener->True,
 FontWeight -> "Light"
 ]

Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 40}]

Cell[StyleData["Input"],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["Output"],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["Code"],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["Program"],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["Text"],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["Item"],
  CellDingbat->StyleBox["\[FilledSmallSquare]", Alignment -> Baseline, 
   RGBColor[0.0, 0.73, 1]],
 CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]

Cell[StyleData["SubitemNumbered"],
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 50}]

Cell[StyleData["Subitem"],
CellDingbat->StyleBox["\[FilledSmallSquare]", Alignment -> Baseline, 
   RGBColor[0.0, 0.2, 1]],
CellGroupingRules->(CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60})]
```

But I still can't find a description of what behavior each of the built in cell grouping types provides.

Comment: My guess is they best realtor to the numeric value within a group namespace and then each namespace is nested realtor to each other, I.e. SectionGrouping is naturally higher than InputGrouping. That is just a guess, 8 have played with it much to verify.

Comment: Sorry typed that on my phone and got a weird typo. My guess is that they first nest according to the numeric value...

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full response, but I have some info that might be helpful.

The subsection issue is caused by the Stylesheet entry for Subsubsection, changing it to the default of 50 should fix it, or anything >40.

```
Cell[
    StyleData["Subsubsection"], 
    CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 50}
]
```

The issue is that the default for SectionGrouping is

- Section -> 30
- Subsection -> 40
- Subsubsection -> 50

You are changing Section and Subsection to be 1, but leaving Subsection at its default.

Sorry, I don't have time now to finish looking at the Item/Subitem stuff, but I will mention that you probably want to be working with `"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping"` rather than `"InputGrouping"` to stay in the same grouping space as list stuff normally resides (look into the Default stylesheet at "Styles for Body Text > Display > Lists > Bulleted").

SIDE NOTE: Your Stylesheet entries have superfluous `CellStyle` arguments, the following expression

```
Cell[StyleData["Subsubsection"], "Subsubsection"]
```

should simply be

```
Cell[StyleData["Subsubsection"]]
```

This is mentioned in the details of the documentation for StyleData:

> Style definition cells have the form `Cell[StyleData["style"],options]`.

It doesn't seem to matter, but seemed worth mentioning.

Cheers